# Kendo dropdown rebind using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

[image]

I am trying to bind a list of `SelectList` Items to a Kendo dropdown in jquery using `dropDown.setDataSource(result)` event. But the issue is, the data displayed in the drop-down is showing as `[object object]`.

```
 $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        var exportTypeDropDown = $("#exportTypeDropDown").data("kendoDropDownList");
        if (dropDownLoaded == false && exportTypeDropDown!=null) {
            dropDownLoaded = true;
                var url = "@Url.Action("GetExportTypes", UiControls.ControllerName)";
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    traditional: true,
                    success: function (result) {
                        exportTypeDropDown.setDataSource(result);
                    }
                });
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think this will help you : http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/dropdownlist/dropdownlist-datasource-binding-help.aspx

Comment: actually by the same reference only i came to this point, but the result what i am getting is a List of SelectListItem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this,
This is just example,

```
       @Html.DropDownList("CustomerId", (SelectList)ViewBag.CustomerNameID, "--Select--")

 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("ddlSearchPNResults")
            .DataTextField("Text")
            .DataValueField("Value")
            .AutoBind(false)
                    .CascadeFrom("CustomerId"))
```

**Script**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CustomerId").change(function () {

            var ddl = $('#ddlSearchPNResults').data("kendoDropDownList");
            var Id = $("#CustomerId").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomerNameWithId", "Test")',
                type: "Post",
                data: { CustomerNameId: Id },
                success: function (listItems) {

                    ddl.setDataSource(listItems);
  }


            });

            });
 });
```

**Controller**

```
 public JsonResult GetCustomerNameWithId(string CustomerNameId)
        {
            int _CustomerNameId = 0;
            int.TryParse(CustomerNameId, out _CustomerNameId);
            var listItems = GetCustomerNameId(_CustomerNameId).Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.CID.ToString(), Text = s.CustomerName }).ToList<SelectListItem>();
            return Json(listItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

It's perfectly working.

Comment: actually i am creating dropdown by using @html.kendo().dropDOwnList().Name("exportTypeDropDown")

Comment: @Rudresh: I just update my code. Try with this and let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 2):

That is because kendo doesn't know which property of `SelectListItem`s object you want to bind with dropdown `Value` and `Text`.

```
$('#exportTypeDropDown').kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "Text",
    dataValueField: "Value",
    autoBind: false
});
```

Make sure you are doing this before setting its `dataSource`.

Comment: Does your browser get proper data from the server? Check from Network tab of browser.

Comment: ya it is getting List of SelectedListItem as [object object],[object object] and in that objects i am getting the data