# Kendo MVC how do I re-populate a dropdownlist using AJAX after initial SelectList?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, dropdownlistfor

I have a Kendo dropdownlist control that I populate via a SelectList on the initial load of the page.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.AssociatedWithType)
    .Events(x => x.Select("CR.TodoAddEditDialog.AssociatedWithSelected"))
    .Value(ViewBag.AssociatedWithTypesId)
    .BindTo(ViewBag.AssociatedWithTypesSelectList)
)

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.AssociatedWithId)
   .BindTo(ViewBag.AssociatedWithIdsSelectList)
)
```

This all works great, but I need to re-load the data when the first dropdown changes value.  I have the following javascript:

```
AssociatedWithSelected: function(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());

    var associatedWithIdsDropDown = $("#todoAddEditDialogForm #AssociatedWithId").data("kendoDropDownList"); 
    var url = settings.getAssociatedWithIdsUrl + "?associatedWithType=" + dataItem.Text;
    associatedWithIdsDropDown.dataSource.read({
        url: url
    });
}
```

However, nothing is being called.

I suspect it's because I've never defined a dataSource in the dropdownlist, but I don't know how to define one in the MVC portion without using it to initially populate the list.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656164/kendo-dropdown-rebind-using-jquery

Comment: Your select event is looking for a function named CR.TodoAddEditDialoge.AssociatedWithSelected instead of your JS function simply AssociatedWithSelected

Comment: @CSharper, yes, I didn't include the namespace code for brevity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this, which seems to work.  There is probably a better way using the Kendo binding, but I still haven't figured out how.

```
AssociatedWithSelected: function(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());

    var associatedWithIdsDropDown = $("#todoAddEditDialogForm #AssociatedWithId").data("kendoDropDownList");

    var url = settings.getAssociatedWithIdsUrl + "?associationType=" + dataItem.Text;
    $.ajax({
        url: url
    })
    .done(function (response) {
        associatedWithIdsDropDown.dataSource.data(response);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't bind the model using viewbag. Heres how you could it from the server.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x => x.FromOpportunity)
          .Name("OpportunityDDL")                 
          .DataTextField("OpportunityName")              
          .DataValueField("OpportunityId")                         
          .DataSource(source => {
              source.Read(read =>
               {
                   read.Action("GetOpportunityListByAccount", "CrmIntegration")
                      .Data("OnAdditionalData");
               })
                . ServerFiltering(true);
          })             
          .HtmlAttributes( new { style = "margin-left:13px; width: 275px;" })
```

Controller
This is kind've pseudo coded but basically return a Json list

```
List<OpportunityViewModel> oppVMList = new List<OpportunityViewModel>();
        var oppList = new OrderManager().GetOpportunitiesByAccount(Id); 

        foreach (var op in oppList)
        {
            OpportunityViewModel opvm = new OpportunityViewModel();
            opvm.OpportunityId = op.OpportunityId;
            opvm.OpportunityName = op.OpportunityName;

            oppVMList.Add(opvm);
        }

    return Json(oppVMList , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And to refresh the ddl

```
 var opportunity = $("#OpportunityDDL").data("kendoDropDownList");
        opportunity.dataSource.read({ Id: advertiserId });
```

your parameter name must be Id

ANy questions just ask :)

Here's my JS function for OnAdditionalData, basically it goes to this function to get the parameter before reading the controller method GetOpportunityListByAccount

```
function OnAdditionalData() {

    var dataItem = $("#Advertisers").data("kendoMultiSelect").value();

    return {
        //call would not work when expecting a Guid, 
        //now it expects a string            
        Id: "" + dataItem
    };
}
```

Comment: Surely there is a way to do what I want.  Doing a bunch of AJAX calls to populate your dropdowns after the form has loaded looks terrible!

Comment: Well it's a cascading dropdown, so based on the value of the multi select field it will re populate the dropdown, hence multiple ajax calls are required. You don't even need the .Data in the read, just simply call read.Action

Comment: I'm a little confused What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Here's my problem.  I have several dropdown lists that need to be populated on this particular form.  If I do dynamic binding to the dropdowns so they all do an ajax call to populate initially, it looks terrible and the functionality sucks because it takes so long for the page to be ready.  So, instead, I get all the data in my controller and populate the dropdowns initially before the HTML ever goes out.  This all works great, however, there is one case where if the user changes 1 drop down, I need to re-load the values of another dropdown via ajax.

Comment: Just call read on the Data Source of the DDL like I have above. You don't have to call read with a parameter if it isn't expecting one. Just say `opportunity.dataSource.read();`

Comment: If I try and attach a data source in the Razor syntax, it ignores the DataBind, so the initial populate doesn't work.  So I can't call a .read, because there is no dataSource to do the read.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking how to create cascading DropDownList. I would suggest you to use the approach covered [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist.html).

Comment: No, I'm not looking to cascade.  I just want the initial population of the dropdown to come from the model, and any refresh of the dropdown to come from the server.